# selenium vba code to zoom out webpage to 60%

Tags: vba, selenium, firefox

I am trying to zoom out webpage to 60% using below code.But this code is not working and also i am not getting any error.Please correct me where i am wrong.

below is my code:-

```html
driver.ExecuteScript ("window.document.body.style.zoom = '60'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zoom out the webpage to 60% you can use either of the following line of code :

```
driver.ExecuteScript "document.body.style.transform='scale(0.6)';"
```

or

```
driver.ExecuteScript "document.body.style.zoom='60%';"
```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, thanks for the reply,actually i am using selenium VBA i thing the script which you have provided is working for java.

Comment: Thanks DebanjanB the code-driver.ExecuteScript("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.6)';") working fine.

Comment: The correct VBA syntax would be driver.ExecuteScript "document.body.style.zoom='60%';"    - no end ; and no ()

Comment: @QHarr Somehow missed your comment earlier. Updated the answer now.