# How to use Selenium WebDriver to reset the zoom to default on Chrome?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I reset **Chrome's zoom level** to Default(100%) using Selenium WebDriver? It's really easy to do using keyboard keys "Ctrl + 0".

However, when I try to emulate this using WebDriver, I can't get anything to work. Here is what I tried without success:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ZoomToDefaultLevelWithChrome()
    {
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.ultimateqa.com");
        var actions = new Actions(driver);
        var browser = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        var html = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html"));

        //None of these work
        actions.SendKeys(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.Add).Perform();
        actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad0).Perform();
        //actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad0).Perform();
        //actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys(html, "0").Perform();
        actions.KeyUp(Keys.Control);
        actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control).Perform();
        actions.SendKeys(html, "0").Perform();
        actions.SendKeys(html, Keys.NumberPad0).Perform();
        actions.SendKeys(Keys.NumberPad0).Perform();

        browser.ExecuteScript("document.body.style.zoom = '1.0'");
        browser.ExecuteScript("document.body.style.transform='scale(1.0)';");
        browser.ExecuteScript("document.body.style.zoom='100%';");

    }
```

The first 2 solutions from here don't work in C#: [Selenium webdriver zoom in/out page content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024756/selenium-webdriver-zoom-in-out-page-content)
Also, this doesn't work in Chrome even though it might in other browsers: [selenium vba code to zoom out webpage to 60%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436067/selenium-vba-code-to-zoom-out-webpage-to-60)

Comment: How did you endup with a zoom different from 100%? The line `new ChromeDriver()` starts an fresh instance/profile with a default zoom level of 100%.

Comment: This is a test of the different zooming options. My real test actually zooms in on my software under test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium vba code to zoom out webpage to 60%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436067/selenium-vba-code-to-zoom-out-webpage-to-60)

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below. This should work.

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.body.style.zoom='100%';");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem, a work around I found was good was setting the the resolution capability

```
capability.SetCapability("resolution", 1920x1080);
```