# Chrome Zoom Set To 100% Using Selenium C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am using below code in selenium c# to make chrome browser zoom to 100% using javascript.but its not working please help

```
var js = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver);
js.ExecuteScript("document.body.style.zoom = '100%';");
```

Comment: Try `document.body.style.zoom = '1.0'`

Comment: Does this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436067/selenium-vba-code-to-zoom-out-webpage-to-60/48437588#48437588

Answer (score 1):

Zoom is a non-standard property, so it's not supported by all browsers.
I'd use transform scale instead, which is supported by all browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

You will need to use prefixes for different browsers, see http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms

```
.example {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Ch <36, Saf 5.1+, iOS < 9.2, An =<4.4.4 */
      -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
          transform: scale(1); /* IE 10, Fx 16+, Op 12.1+ */
}
```

For your chrome use case, you would use:

```
document.body.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)'
```